# How to set category in logger in flutter using logger.dart

Tags: logging, flutter, dart

I'm using the `package:logger/logger.dart` to log messages to the console area of the Run tab which appears as:

```
20:45:48.622 info flutter.tools    MapsDemo - _pushPage<…>
```

This is the code

```
class MyLogger extends PrettyPrinter {
    final String className;
    MyLogger(this.className);
    @override
    void log(Level level, message, error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
        var color = PrettyPrinter.levelColors[level];
        var emoji = PrettyPrinter.levelEmojis[level];
        println(color('$emoji $className - $message'));
    }
}

Logger getLogger(Object className) {
    return Logger(printer:  MyLogger(className.runtimeType.toString()));
}
```

And how it's invoked:

```
Logger log = getLogger(this);
log.i("_pushPage", );
```

So I want to change the *category* which I believe is the `flutter.tools` portion of the console listing to something of my own choosing.

Comment: Which version of `logger` are you using? (Check in `pubspec.lock`)

Comment: logger: ^0.6.0.  This could very well be a console issue because I tried using `'package:logging/logging.dart'` and the category is the same.  The settings on the console does refer to it as a Category.  I would just love to know where that 'flutter.tools' is coming from.

Comment: IntelliJ? Open settings>Languages and Frameworks>Flutter and clear the experimental console output checkbox.

Comment: Ok thanks - you are correct that option is where the formatting was coming from.  I went down a rabbit hole when I saw that logcat was not supported in Flutter.  I ended with a simple logger wrapper for logging.dart to console - but there is no filtering in console from what I can see.